# Problems overloading << operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am getting some problems overloading the << operator.
The error is this one: 'JSON' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'

How is the correct method to overload the operator <<.
My objective is to be able to do std::cout<

My code is:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "JSON.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"JSON V0.1"<<std::endl;

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file;
    std::stringstream ss;
    JSON obj;

    file.open("test.json");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout<<"File opened"<<std::endl;
        ss << file.rdbuf();

        obj.parse(ss);
        file.close();
     }

     std::cout<<obj<<std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

JSON.hpp

```
#ifndef _JSON_H_
#define _JSON_H_

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

class JSON
{
    public:
        bool parse(std::stringstream &stream);
        std::string get(std::string &key);

    private:
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
};
#endif
```

JSON.cpp

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include "JSON.hpp"

bool JSON::parse(std::stringstream &stream)
{
    boost::property_tree::read_json(stream, pt);
    return true;
}

std::string JSON::get(std::string &key)
{
    std::string rv = "null";
    return rv;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const JSON& json)
{
    return out << "JSON" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler only considers functions that it has seen before when it sees a function call, so it doesn't see the `operator<<` you have in the .cpp file.

You must put a forward declaration of your `operator<<` somewhere so the compiler knows about it, like in the header:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const JSON&);
```

Then the compiler will know about the function when it sees you call it.

Comment: If I do that I get this error:
g++ -O2 -o main.o -c main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
JSON.hpp:11:65: error: 'std::ostream& JSON::operator<<(std::ostream&, const JSON&)' must take exactly one argument
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: @user1236117 put it outside the class, it's a global function not a member function.

Comment: Other question, it is possible to have a operator overloading virtual, so descent class are oblige to implemented?

Comment: @user1236117 yes, but remember that calls are only virtual through pointers or references, and that it's not possible to have a class override a non-member function like this one. You can work around that though, for example make your class have a virtual function `print(std::ostream&)` and then have the global `operator<<` call `print(out)` on the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a declaration of the `ostream& operator<<` in `JSON.hpp`, after the declaracion of class `JSON`:

```
// JSON.hpp
....
class JSON
{
  // as before
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const JSON& json);
```

Comment: If I do that I get this error:
g++ -O2 -o main.o -c main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
JSON.hpp:11:65: error: 'std::ostream& JSON::operator<<(std::ostream&, const JSON&)' must take exactly one argument
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: @user1236117 make sure to put it **after** the declaration of class `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of the `operator<<` needs to be available to `main`. Put it into the header file.

Comment: If I do that I get this error:
g++ -O2 -o main.o -c main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
JSON.hpp:11:65: error: 'std::ostream& JSON::operator<<(std::ostream&, const JSON&)' must take exactly one argument
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: It has to be a free function, not a member of your class.